# An array or Generic collection?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, generics, collections

I need to pass a list of Days (number and name) to an view!

Whats the best way to do this?

I was thinking of creating a generic collection, but not sure how? or an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dictionary<string, int> days = new Dictionary<string, int>();

days.Add("Sunday", 1);
```

...

Answer (score 2):

Why not an enum?

```
enum days
{ 
    Monday = 1,
    Tuesday = 2
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For something like this you can use a dictionary... simple key/value pairs

```
Dim d as New Dictionary(Of Integer, String)
d.Add(0,"string2")
'   etc
```

Answer (score 0):

You really ought to use an `IEnumerable<T>`.  Add a `List<T>` to the ViewData and then cast it as an `IEnumerable<T>` on the other side.

Answer (score -2):

If I only had those 2 options, I'd use an Array.

Because an array is immutable. You can't accidentally "add" or "removes" something which is what the view should be. It's kind of a defensive programming.

And you can still use `foreach` just fine.... so why goes Collection? no need at all.

Comment: Arrays are mutable. You can use List.AsReadOnly to get a readonly view of a list to send elsewhere.

Comment: @Ben Lings An array is immutable when used in a *normal* way. I didn't say that objects contained in an array aren't immutable. And the author asks for either Collection *or* an array... as I've said in the first sentence....

Comment: Arrays are constant length, but have mutable elements.

Comment: See http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2008/09/22/arrays-considered-somewhat-harmful.aspx

Comment: @Ben Lings and did I said otherwise?